# How to optimize a DQL query in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, query-optimization

I have an entity called **Abono** that is the parent class of several other entities like Cheque, Efectivo, Debito and so on. In my application I'm querying all the objects that are instances of the class Abono using a repository class with a DQL statement like this (the code is a simplified version of the real one):

```php
$dql = "SELECT ab FROM FranquiciaBundle:Abono AS ab";
return $em->createQuery($dql)
          ->getResult();
```

In my template I'm showing the results like this (again, simplified code):

```html
{% for abono in abonos %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ abono.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ abono.tipo }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I have 5000 records on that table and the profiler is telling me that the app is hitting 5000 times the database instead of just once as I expected, so I change que repository a bit using `getArrayResult()` instead of `getResult()` but the problem is that the sentence `{{ abono.tipo }}` is a method call of the object, not a property stored in the database so it never gets hydrated into the result array.

So my question is, **how can I get an array of objects hitting the database just once?**

**UPDATE:** The method `getTipo()` of the class Abono returns the Late Static Binding class name of every object, it's not an association.

```php
public function getTipo()
{
    $className = get_called_class();
    $pos = strrpos($className,'\\');
    return substr($className, $pos+1);
}
```

Comment: Before I type up an answer... Why aren't you using Entity Models to make this query? Have you considered a one-to-many relationship?

Comment: Well, the method getTipo() is not an association, it returns the Late Static Binding (LSB) class name of the current object because every object in the result set is an instance of the class Cheque, Efectivo, Debito or any other child class of Abono and I want to show that in my template. I'm going to update my question to show what I mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I found the origin of my problem.

It seems that when querying for **objects that are the inverse side of an association**, doctrine will **always** fetch those entities to create proxy instances, even if those entities are not needed in the controller or the template. So the huge amount of hits to the database that the profile bar was showing me, was really doctrine getting in the way searching for information that I was not asking for.

The solution is to force the use of **partial load** in the repository like this:

```php
$dql = "SELECT ab FROM FranquiciaBundle:Abono AS ab";
return $em->createQuery($dql)
          ->setHint(Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true)
          ->getResult();
```

More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848747/primary-key-of-owning-side-as-a-join-column)

Comment: I must say, Many thanks this reduced my amount of queries from 34 to 11 and solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use a fetch join to grab the related information and hydrate it along with the first query.

"SELECT ab, tipo FROM FranquiciaBundle:Abono AS ab JOIN ab.tipo"

See also:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins

Comment: The problem is that `tipo` is not an association, it's the LSB class name of the object. See the update of my question

Answer (score 1):

Erik is right, however you shouldn't have to go down sql to optimize, a doSelectJoinAll will do the trick.

Comment: How a fetch join would help me if `tipo` it's not an association?

Comment: I don't se way it hits the db when calling tipo (type for non-spanish speakers). But David why don't you designed your db the usual way, with a foreign key to a table "tipo". This code looks like a hack to deal with that design, and of course the performance is not the same.

Comment: Because when you set an inheritance model using Doctrine (with multiple tables), the parent table has a field with the child class name of every record, so creating a new table to hold that information seems redundant to me. The problem is that this field is hidden in DQL and can't be used directly.

Comment: Wow, you pulled a hard one, I avoid table inheritance in the schema because of this kind of quirks. Relational model is to nice to mess around, I rather do it manually.