# Auto database query from User entity in Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

In Symfony2, I have these columns in a user entity:

```
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="lovername")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lover", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete = "SET NULL")
 */
private $lover;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="lover", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 **/
private $lovername;
```

The project is a dating website, where a user can send messages only to one user, which he/she chose. The column `lover` contains the id of user he/she chose to talk to.

It works properly, but it generates an additional SQL query. First Symfony downloads the row about the logged user and then every information about user which 'love' him, even if that information is useless. I need it only when user sends messages.

It is some way to write it/build database better? How do I control auto-generating queries in Symfony2?

Comment: Could you paste those queries?

Comment: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.username [...] FROM users t0 LEFT JOIN users [...] WHERE t0.id = ?
And second query:
SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.username [...] FROM users t0 LEFT JOIN users [...] WHERE t0.lover = ?

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced a similar problem. It seems like `LazyLoad` doesn't work properly for `OneToOne` relationships in doctrine. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848747/primary-key-of-owning-side-as-a-join-column)